# Conceptual Query related to Modulo arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Came across an expression given below

$$321^{984} \equiv 6^{984} \equiv(-1)^{984}\equiv 1 \pmod{7}$$

Now $321^{984} \equiv 6^{984} \pmod{n}$ is understood

and $6^{984} \equiv (-1)^{984} \equiv 1^{984} \pmod{n} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$

but then how is $321^{984} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ ?

I know that if

$a\equiv b \pmod{n}$     and 
$c \equiv d \pmod{n}$   then

$a+c \equiv b+d \pmod{n}$  or

$ac \equiv bd \pmod{n}$

But Equation (I) looks something of the type

$a \equiv b \pmod{n}$  and $b \equiv c \pmod{n}$  then

$a \equiv c \pmod{n}$

Can someone explain this? I think I am missing some simple idea here. Please help me understand this.

Comment: $a\equiv b\pmod n$ means that $a-b$ is divisible by $n$. We have that $a-c = (a-b) + (b-c)$ so if both $a-b$ and $b-c$ are divisible by $n$ then so is $a-c$. In the modular arithmetics language this statement is just: $a\equiv b\pmod n$ and $b\equiv c \pmod n$ implies $a\equiv c\pmod  n$.

Comment: Informally: $x\equiv y\pmod{n}$ means that $x$ and $y$ have the same remainder when divided by $n$. If $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder, and $b$ and $c$ have the same remainder, then $a$ and $c$ have the same remainder.

Answer (score 1):

"Congruent mod $n$" is an equivalence relation.  In particular, it is transitive.  So, if $a\equiv b \mod n$ and $b\equiv c\mod n$, then $a \equiv c \mod n$.  It's just like equality:  If $a = b $ and $b=c$, then $a=c$.